# PostgreSQL: how to copy constraints and indexes from another table after populating the table

Tags: postgresql, indexing, constraints, indices

I am running PostgreSQL 9.3.4 on Windows. For many of the tables in my database, I need to create another version of the tables, in another schema, with fewer records (as determined by a simple condition).

For example, say I have a public.orders table with 15 million records. I want to create a myschema.orders table with only the orders placed after 1-Jan-2010. This condition reduces the table from 15 to 1.5 million records.

My problem: I want myschema.orders to have the same constraints and indices as public.orders, but I'd like to add them after populating the table as this should be faster. I'd rather not use a view because it would be much slower. I can do:

```
create table myschema.orders (like public.orders including all);
insert into myschema.orders select * public.orders where MyCondition = True
```

The first line copies all constraints (excluding foreign keys) and indices before populating the table. The code works, but is about 15 times slower than inserting the same records into a table with no constraints.

What is the easiest way to populate the table first, and then copying the constraints? Or can I maybe disable and then re-enable the constraints? I need to do this for about 30 tables, each of which with about 10 constraints and 7 indices, so I'd like to automate the process as much as possible.

Thank you!

Comment: I have tried: BEGIN TRANSACTION; CREATE TABLE ...; SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED; INSERT INTO ... ; COMMIT; but the time is the same